# In Markdown, math is centred environment makes errors

Tags: math, markdown

It seems that

```
<center>Blah... $s_x$ blah</center>
```

does not subscript the way it should. On the other hand, if I remove  tags subscript x looks just fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Standard Markdown doesn't have any special support for math. `$` doesn't have any special meaning. Which Markdown processor are you using? Are you also using something like MathJAX?

Comment: Well, I am working in Sublime and/or SubEthaEdit, typically. I do not use MathJAX.

Comment: Sublime and SubEthaEdit are _editors_, not Markdown processors. What tool are you using to render your Markdown to HTML?

Comment: Ouch, so sorry, I've misread the question. Actually, I am using Marked2, side by side with Sublime, and I export (render) when needed from it to pdf or docx etc.

Comment: By default [Marked2 uses MultiMarkdown](http://marked2app.com/help/MultiMarkdown_Information.html) which in turn [uses MathML](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/blob/master/Documentation/MultiMarkdown%20User%27s%20Guide.md#math-syntax), which "is not fully supported in many browsers, so your mileage may vary". Which browser are you using to view the rendered content? You can also [configure Marked2 to use Discount](http://marked2app.com/help/MultiMarkdown_Information.html#alternativerenderingviadiscount) which [uses MathJax](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount). Try that.

Comment: If this works I can add a proper answer below.

Comment: Hi [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris), Interestingly enough, I had my Markdown2 setup for Discount rendering. (I did it long ago and forgot it!) This did not work. However, when I switched to MultiMarkdown I got the proper math subscript. Then, one last bit is not to use `$$ SOME EQUATION $$` but `\\[ SOME EQUATION \\]`. Then you have all working properly.

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. Please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so other users can benefit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) we together managed to find the right answer for this question: As I am using `Marked2` under the latest `macOS` the right solution for processing the markdown files is to set the rendering to `MultiMarkdown` and then to use strictly

```
\\[ SOME EQUATION \\]
```

and not

```
$$ SOME EQUATION $$
```

Then, `center` environment will work properly and with subscripts like `$w_e$`